# Shading in bookcover

Tags: shading, bookcover

I'm trying to make a book cover using the `bookcover` class. The problem is that I cannot use shade (something I want to use), it always gives a black background, even with the minimal example in the 
[user manual](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bookcover/bookcover.pdf)

```
\documentclass[flapwidth=50mm,spinewidth=15mm]{bookcover}

\begin{document}
 \begin{bookcover}
    \bookcovercomponent{color}{bg whole without flaps}{
        top color=white, bottom color=blue!50!black, shading angle=60}
 \end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```

According to the manual it is no necessary to include `tikz` and `xcolor` packages manually, but even doing so I get the same result.

Some one can see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Works for me (albeit not very fine looking, probably due to the white \topcolor. Did you really have your problem with this very code?

Comment: The code succeeds when compiled with pdflatex or lualatex, producing a cover that is shaded from white (upper left) to blue (most of the area). The code FAILS when compiled with xelatex, producing solid black.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the manual of class `bookcover` I can not find that there could be a problem with XeLaTeX, but if I compile your given code code I get the following results:

- PdfLaTeX: Compiles without error or warnings, shows white to blue.
- luaLaTeX: compiles without error or warnings, shows white to blue.
- XeLaTeX:  compiles without error or warnings, but shows only a black block.

My used TeX distribution is a current MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 8.

Result with PdfLaTeX:

[image: with pdflatex]

You should make a bug report ...

Answer (score 1):

This bug is fixed in [version 2.2](https://ctan.org/pkg/bookcover)

If you use version 2.1, then the next code works with xelatex, lualatex and pdflatex too:

```
\documentclass[flapwidth=50mm,spinewidth=15mm]{bookcover}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter\TP@absposfalse\makeatother\newgeometry{left=0em,top=-1em} % fixing code
 \begin{bookcover}
    \bookcovercomponent{color}{bg whole without flaps}{
           top color=white, bottom color=blue!50!black, shading angle=60}
 \end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```